# The [kotlinx-date-time] tag should be renamed to drop that second hyphen (a misspelling)

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I found the [kotlinx-date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx-date-time) tag. That tag represents the library [*kotlinx-datetime*](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime#kotlinx-datetime).

Notice the difference in spelling. The tag was incorrectly named with a second hyphen. The tag should be [kotlinx-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx-datetime).

According to [this meta page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87437/203321), the way to rename a tag is to post here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

6/6 questions have been retagged; [kotlinx-date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx-date-time) no longer exists. [kotlinx-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlinx-datetime) is now appropriately named:

```
updating post history, 6 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 6 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'kotlinx-datetime' doesn't exist, renaming 'kotlinx-date-time' to 'kotlinx-datetime'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [kotlinx-datetime] and [kotlinx-date-time] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```